# Centered text in a tabular row

Tags: tables

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering\scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \arraybackslash Medi\c{c}\~{a}o (cm)\\
    \midrule
    Ensaios & 1 & 2 & 3 & M\'{e}dia\\
    \hline Comprimento (b) (cm) & 49,90 & 49,80 & 49,80 & 49,83\\
    \hline Largura (a) (cm) & 2,10 & 2,00 & 2,05 & 2,05\\
    \hline Dist\^{a}ncia do CM (cm) & 24,95 & 24,90 & 24,90 & 24,90\\
    \hline d (dist\^{a}ncia do CM at\'{e} ao eixo de rota\c{c}\~{a}o) (cm) 
    & 19,20 & 19,25 &  19,15 & 19,20\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I wanna put the text "Medições" in the middle of the first line of the `tabular`. How I can do this?

Comment: `\multicolumn{5}{c}{Medições}`

Comment: Very good. I'll add an answer then. And btw: Next time kick out everything that is irrellevant to the question. Clearer example=better help! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\centering\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{Medi\c{c}\~{a}o (cm)}\\
  \midrule
  Ensaios & 1 & 2 & 3 & M\'{e}dia\\
  \hline Comprimento (b) (cm) & 49,90 & 49,80 & 49,80 & 49,83\\
  \hline Largura (a) (cm) & 2,10 & 2,00 & 2,05 & 2,05\\
  \hline Dist\^{a}ncia do CM (cm) & 24,95 & 24,90 & 24,90 & 24,90\\
  \hline d (dist\^{a}ncia do CM at\'{e} ao eixo de rota\c{c}\~{a}o) (cm) 
  & 19,20 & 19,25 &  19,15 & 19,20\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use too many horizontal rules, and anyway, avoid mixing ‘normal’ `\hrule`s and `\rules` from `booktabs`. I suggest using instead some vertical padding above and below cells with `cellspace`. In addition  you can have vertical alignment on the decimal comma in columns 2 to 5:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathtools,float,geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,tabularx,threeparttablex, cellspace, siunitx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \scriptsize \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}Cc*{4}{S[table-format = 2.2,output-decimal-marker={,}]}@{}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{5}{Cc}{Medição (cm)} \\
    \midrule
    Ensaios & {1} & {2} & 3 & {Média} \\
    Comprimento (b) (cm) & 49,90 & 49,80 & 49,80 & 49,83 \\
    Largura (a) (cm) & 2,10 & 2,00 & 2,05 & 2,05 \\
    Distância do CM (cm) & 24,95 & 24,90 & 24,90 & 24,90 \\
    d (distância do CM até ao eixo de rotação) (cm)
                          & 19,20 & 19,25 & 19,15 & 19,20 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although the detail you added to your answer is rather helpful to the O.P. it is prety irrellevant to the OP, hence this is more of an extended comment.

Comment: I know. Strictly answering the question consists in your answer. I thought it useful to help the O.P. (and  maybe others) showing how to have a nicer table.

Comment: ... which is not bad in general. I think we have different opinions to which extent this is worth a completely new answer, though. What was possible anyways is to write your contribution as a comment without the inline code. (And just as a side note: I don't want to be picky, but objectively speaking this Q&A format is meant to answer specific questions defined by the questioner, i.e. "strictly answering the question" and not to add whatever I think might be good while reading the OP, as in a discussion forum.)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have obsession with this table ...

This time your problem will be solved with use:

```
    \toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Medi\c{c}\~{a}o (cm)}\\
    \midrule
```

and resulting looks of table is:

[image]